# ngf-select causing opening window while swiping on phone

Tags: angularjs, swipe, bxslider, ng-file-upload

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I see lots of Questions regarding `ng-click` event triggered while swiping images on phone. and there are lots of solutions on this. But I have placeholders when I click on it, it should open a window to select image using `ngf-select(danielfarid's)` which will open a window when swipe event compeleted, I tried detecting swipe trigger and tried not adding images based on flag set after detecting swipe trigger. But still the window is getting opened as soon as user ended swipe.

I am using bxslider to show gallery where we have pager and the image selected, so when I try to scroll pager in mobile using swipe it causes opening window to select file. as the last three placehodlers have functions to upload image using ngf-select.

this is the code for placeholder i am using to select images

```
 <a  ngf-select="uploadImage($files)" >
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle mainimg"></i>
                <img ng-src="img/plus.png" class="tb_gal"/>
      </a>
```

Comment: If you look at the source code of select.js you will see that there is an attempt to detect the touch event and ignore it if the touch is happening for too long: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/src/select.js#L132 this might give you an idea.

Comment: @danial ok so you mean this should work ? Or do I need to make any change for this ?

Comment: As I see in the code it checks only for Y axis, what if user scrolls to x - axis, Sorry If I misunderstood this.

Comment: True! open an issue on the github page please to fix this for X axis as well.

Comment: sure - https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/1676

Comment: fixed at version 12.2.5

Comment: Ok Thanks! @danial

Answer (score 0):

So the case of horizontal swipe is handled in v 12.2.5 and this issue is resolved in ng-file-upload/danielfarid v 12.2.5.